# Morphing a tiled diamond pattern around organic objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I'm a complete beginner trying to replicate this "Cocoon" object.

I tried to make the tiled pattern by using several rotated cubes (to create a diamond) joined together by using array modifier and then creating the tiled effect by simply duplicating the first set of cubes and alternating them in such a way that the succeeding level of the set of cubes is lower than the previous set.

I wanted to morph the pattern onto an object using the shrinkwrap modifier. However, I've had no success in doing so.

I tried to shrinkwrap the pattern onto a cylinder, and fortunately, it worked.
However, on natural objects it just ends up deforming the pattern altogether, diminishing the "tiled" effect in the end.

Ideally, I'd like the pattern to be able to morph to any object without it deforming.

Is there any other way to do this?

<sup>A "Cocoon" at Baku Airport, Azerbaijan</sup>
[image: A "Cocoon" at Baku Airport, Azerbaijan]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> Subdivide the default cube
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> on the subdivision modifier to apply it
- go to Edit Mode, <kbd>F3</kbd> *Checker Deselect*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> bevel vertices, drag

[image]

If you assign every other vertex (selection after *Checker Deselect*) to a group, you can use modifiers:

[image]

*Weld* is needed for smooth shading, but it defeats the purpose...